# PL/SQL error ORA-00904: invalid identifier using merge, select and set

Tags: select, plsql, merge, set, ora-00904

I'm new to PL/SQL. I've created a table called orders which has a pk as orders_id and a products table with a pk as products_id. Both are numbers 1 through 10. In the orders table is a column called item_name, which I want to merge into the products column called item_name.

This is what I have tried:

```
MERGE INTO products
USING ( 
    SELECT item_name
    FROM orders) 
ON (orders.order_id = products.product_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET 
    products.item_name = orders.item_name
```

AND

```
MERGE INTO products
USING ( 
    SELECT item_name
    FROM orders) 
ON (products.product_id=orders.order_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET 
    products.item_name2 = orders.item_name
```

I keep getting the error "ORA-00904: "ORDERS"."ORDER_ID": invalid identifier". I've checked order_id is a NUMBER the same as the product_id. I have also created a column in products called item_name2, but that didn't work either. What does the error mean? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> select * from orders;

 ORDERS_ID ITEM_N
---------- ------
         1 Name A
         2 Name B
         3 Name C
         5 Name E

SQL> select * from products;

PRODUCTS_ID ITEM_NAME
----------- ----------
          1
          2
          3
          4
```

Updating `products.item_name` from the `orders` table:

```
SQL> merge into products p
  2    using orders o
  3    on (o.orders_id = p.products_id)
  4  when matched then update set
  5    p.item_name = o.item_name;

3 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from products;

PRODUCTS_ID ITEM_NAME
----------- ----------
          1 Name A
          2 Name B
          3 Name C
          4               --> no matching IDs, so it is left empty
 
SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and taking the time to answer :)